# Github FTP Deploy: fatal: Not a Git project? Exiting... On GitHub Actions Tab while running the workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, repo

I am trying to deploy my changes to live server using GitHub via ftp workflow but it keeps on failing on
'fatal: Not a Git project? Exiting...'

```
FTP-Deploy-Action Error Log:
  Forced mode enabled.
  Auto init if needed.
  Using syncroot ./ if exists.
  Insecure SSL/TLS connection allowed
  fatal: Not a Git project? Exiting... <------------------------- fails from here
  The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 8
>
```

```
I did 'git init' as stated in helpful articles but that didn't helped.
I re-clone the git repo and pushed the changes again and still having the same issue with the repo.

It was working fine until now.

Thank you for your time.
```

Comment: formatting needs to be edited

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a docker image being updated and is now resolved. See the github issue for more information https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action/issues/345

No updates to your github action are required to use the new (patched) version.

Answer (score 0):

It's allready fixed :)
See here: https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action/issues/345#issuecomment-1353339618

Comment: While links are okay, it's best to include the key information without requiring people to click the link. Please edit your question with key points.